# Create block in template.php

Tags: theming

I have the feeling that I'm doing something stupid or missing something obvious...
I want to create a block in template.php in my custom template but it is not showing in admin/structure/block
The code i use is simple:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function MYTHEMENAME_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['eeeeeeee'] = array(
    // The name that will appear in the block list.
    'info' => t('eeeeeeeeeee'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```

Then i created a custom module, to see if a have a typo,  with the same code. Just changed MYTHEMENAME with MYMODULENAME and I can see it in admin/structure/block

1. I tried changing MYTHEMENAME to phptemplate
2. Cleared the cache many times

Is it even possible to create a block in template.php?

Comment: Right at the top of the api docs for [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) it says: Define all blocks provided by the module.

Comment: You are right. Now i have to change some development desigions i made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible. You would create the custom block in a module, add content to it there as well. Then you can theme it or call it in various places inside your theme as well as theme the actual block. That is the usual use scenario for blocks. I will try to add some links in just a bit with more explanation.

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial to learn how to create custom blocks: http://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/building-custom-blocks-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks for the link. But the problem is to make it work in template.php